# React with CiviCRM APIs

Tags: api

I am trying to use the CiviCRM APIs from my React application. Which API methods would be the one recommended or easy to do with React application ? The easiest would be REST but since my page and civicrm will be hosted on the same machine, I prefer not to go down the REST route.

I read that CiviMobile uses react but didn't get too much information on its implementation.

Any recommendation and also examples or tutorials that I can reference ?

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea what your React application is so I am not going to be able to answer your question easily :-)

There is an API section in the CiviCRM Developer Guide that should help you: https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/api/

Comment: There are several ways to use the APIs - would like to know which of the methods would be the best for a React application to use. Would it be PHP, REST, AJAX, etc ?

Comment: As stated, I have no idea what your React application is so I do not know. Will it access CiviCRM from another server? If so, the REST is best.